# VPN works for windows 2003, but not for windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, vpn

I have a RRAS VPN on a Windows server 2008 r2 server. Now when I try to connect to it, from a windows 2003 box, it works fine. However, it doesn't work when I try to connect to it from a windows server 2008 box, it gives me an error 803.

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From MS support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824864):

> 803
>   The PEAP configuration stored in the session cookie does not match the current session configuration.

Sounds like your 2008 box isn't configured properly for the security requirements of your VPN, or you need to clear out its cache.  (Probably the configuration one, though.)  [Here's a quick guide on setting up PEAP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd314152%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for 2k8/2k12 that might help you out.